# What is Darth Vader holding on the cover of the original Star Wars novelization?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, darth-vader, a-new-hope, object-identification

On the cover of some versions of *Star Wars: From the Adventures of Luke Skywalker*, Darth Vader is holding something in his hand.

[image: Star Wars novel cover art 1]

[image: Star Wars novel cover art 2]

It seems to be comprised of some strings with multicolored objects hanging off of them. Do we know what it's supposed to be?

Comment: What is *Luke* holding?

Comment: I don't think he is holding anything. I think it's part of the overplayed scenery. Vader is holding up a clenched fist and it just looks like he's holding something. But that's opinion and unverifiable.

Comment: @Adamant Some sort of proto-lightsaber, I'd assume.

Comment: Looks to me like he's crushing something, and the debris is falling from his hand.

Comment: Like it or not: it's a bottle of Gin. Met this guy at an AA meeting.

Comment: "From the adventures of Luke Skywalker" - sounds like the series was originally intended to be all about Luke.

Comment: @ThomasW The original trilogy pretty much *is* all about Luke... Sure, some great supporting characters, but the focus is clearly centrally focused on Luke's journey from backwater farm boy to Jedi saving the galaxy from evil. Almost every event in the movies is important to that progression.

Comment: Why does the Death Star share similar lighting to Vader, and as an outcome look like a mirror ball about a foot away from his shoulder ??

Answer (score 61, accepted):

In the original John Berkey painting, it appears that Vader is holding his lightsaber, stylized in a similar manner to Luke's lightsaber. (In fact, it almost looks like a solid metal blade with light glinting off it to me, but I think that's just stylization.)

Berkey's illustrations from early in the history of Star Wars were done with minimal access to information about the film as it was being made. As such, his Star Wars work is also notable for occasional inaccuracies. (For instance, one painting of the Death Star battle features multiple Millennium Falcon-like ships, since he didn't know that model was used as a unique ship in the film.)

The multicolored streaks below his hand seem to be just another stylistic flourish, typical of Berkey's painting. They may represent motion lines, as the color used is similar to the red-orange "contrails" left by the Y-Wings at the left of the image.

[image]

Comment: To be honest, I kinda like this version of the lightsaber better. Instead of a big colored beam, it's more of a subtle glint.

Comment: I never realized that both Vader and Luke were left-handed.

Comment: @ssdecontrol then you may find the [darksaber](http://img.lum.dolimg.com/v1/images/databank_darksaber_01_169_0bab10aa.jpeg?region=0%2C0%2C1560%2C878&width=768) of interest.

Answer (score 39):

They appear to be simple motion lines. You may wish to note that they also appear on earlier (and stylistically cruder) [version of the same picture](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2014/10/11/star-wars-posters_n_5948808.html) by [the same artist](http://www.joblo.com/movie-news/check-out-these-cool-rare-and-unseen-star-wars-posters-274)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I want a print of that first one!

Comment: The second image looks like a scene from a really happening discotheque.

Comment: @Joecoehoorn - I get my posters and prints from www.photobox.co.uk  The picture above has sufficient pixels to blow it up into a poster size.

Comment: @DetectiveChimp You mean like one run by [this guy?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MRHdv1IU4po)